# This is regarding Bigquery audit logging

Tags: logging, google-bigquery, audit

[Sample scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdB9h.png)
Would like to understand is there any column from BQ audit table which will give me bytes-second . I do see billed bytes and processed bytes but could not find a column bytes- second

Background of the request :

When we verified our billing , specific to bigquery we could see that usage unit in bytes showing proper query cost which is matching with the audit table but a larger amount is shown under byte-second and could not isolate this from audit table for further debugging

Tried to check for this columns availability but could not find anything yet

Comment: Any help on above topic ? BigQuery API specific cost is the main concern specific to above issue. We don't have much job running in DEV instance actually hence confused about from where the cost is getting generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the issue , it was more related to long term physical and long term logical bytes specific to unused test tables in our dev instance which was causing surges in overall bytes per second values against Bigquery in our billing. After retiring such tables from the instance brought back the billing to normal